# .net core Update Service Reference missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wcf

In my .net core 3.1 project I have consumed SOAP Web Service. After I moved on new PC and system, I downloaded VS 2019, cloned project but then when I tried to Update my Web Reference I saw that WCF section in my project has changed.
I think I need to install something additionaly to my Visual Studio but I couldnt find anything 'WCF' that isnt installed in VS Installer.

I dont have this button anymore (***Update Service Reference***):

(Example screen from youtube):

[image]

I didnt 'add connected service' to this project by myself so I dont know if I did something wrong after downloading visual studio again.
Now, when I want to update service reference I must go to **Connected Serice>Edit** and then search for wsdl and then update, but the process is same as adding new conencted service.
I think I might be missing some visual studio extension.

When I update my Service "new way" then in 'ConnectedService.json' these two lines are deleted:

> "ProviderId": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ConnectedService.Wcf",
> "Version": "15.0.40203.910",

Next thing is when I "add service reference" option "Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider" isnt available, but "WCF Web Service" is.
[image]

My visual studio 2019 enterprise version is up-to date.

Comment: Same problem in VS2022. Been like that since at least a year for me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

And as for the answer, posted by a MS person on a post in their forum:

> The behavior you’ve observed that “Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference
> Provider” isn’t there on 16.10.4 is a change by-design. Start from
> 16.11, you are supposed to add a service reference via right clicking solution and then choose **“Add” -> “Connected Service”,** then in the
> left panel click “Service References (OpenAPI, gRPC, WCF Web
> Service)”, in the popped up list select “WCF Web Service” and go
> though the wizards to add a service reference.
>
> To update an existing service, open the “Service References (OpenAPI,
> gRPC, WCF Web Service)” panel, **click “…” beside the existing service
> which you want to update and then select “Edit” in the dropped down
> menu item, complete the popped up wizards to update that service.**

Comment: They really need to bring the old refresh button back.

Comment: And, after much testing, their solution is NOT working. The service reference is not updated, even if you Edit it from there. The only way is to delete it and redo it.

Comment: Also, the new approach to service generation doesn't generate the implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged; and although [there is a way to configure it to do that](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2205#issuecomment-490633884) the wizard UI [does not expose that option](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/please-add-a-checkbox-for-enabledatabindings-to-mi/1165673); so being forced to go through the wizard to re-generate it is a non-starter for me.

Answer (score 1):

Not Missing. It is transferred to Project/Connected Services.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).